# Elegant way to animate color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, background-color

I have 3 tabs which should have different background and text color. I have created 3 classes in CSS with this styles (collor-pallet-1, 2, 3). I am currently doing this ugly thing which also does not work smoothly. Surely there must be a better way to do this? Thanks

```
$("#tab1").click(function() {

    $(".resp-tab-content").addClass("color-pallet-1");
    if ($(".resp-tab-content").hasClass("color-pallet-2")) {
        $(".resp-tab-content").removeClass("color-pallet-2", 500);
    }
    if ($(".resp-tab-content").hasClass("color-pallet-3")) {
        $(".resp-tab-content").removeClass("color-pallet-3", 500)
    }
    $(".tab-background").css("background-color", function() {
        return $(".resp-tab-content").css("background-color");
        console.log($(".resp-tab-content").css("background-color"));
    });
});
$("#tab2").click(function() {

    $(".resp-tab-content").addClass("color-pallet-2");
    if ($(".resp-tab-content").hasClass("color-pallet-1")) {
        $(".resp-tab-content").removeClass("color-pallet-1", 500);
    }
    if ($(".resp-tab-content").hasClass("color-pallet-3")) {
        $(".resp-tab-content").removeClass("color-pallet-3", 500);
    }
    $(".tab-background").css("background-color", function() {
        return $(".resp-tab-content").css("background-color");
        console.log($(".resp-tab-content").css("background-color"));
    });
});
$("#tab3").click(function() {

     $(".resp-tab-content").addClass("color-pallet-3");
     if ($(".resp-tab-content").hasClass("color-pallet-2")) {
         $(".resp-tab-content").removeClass("color-pallet-2", 500);
     }
     if ($(".resp-tab-content").hasClass("color-pallet-1")) {
         $(".resp-tab-content").removeClass("color-pallet-1", 500);
     }
     $(".tab-background").css("background-color", function() {
         return $(".resp-tab-content").css("background-color");
         console.log($(".resp-tab-content").css("background-color"));
     });
});
```

Comment: jQuery `removeClass()` method doesn't accept a duration parameter. If you are including any other plugin, e.g jQuery UI, you should really including tag in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to give a time parameter to `.removeClass()` but when you think about it, an element either has a class or doesn't, there is no transition. Luckily, with CSS3 you don't need javascript to animate colors! To accomplish a smooth transition, give your base class (something like `.tab`) a rule like `transition: background-color 0.5s ease;` (with appropriate browser prefixes) and the starting colors. Give your color-palette classes the colors you want to transition to. You can then use some simple javascript to just toggle the color-palette classnames.  CSS Tricks has (as usual) a useful article on CSS3 transitions here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this plugin

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Sample code of color animation

```
jQuery("#go").click(function(){
   jQuery("#block").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#abcdef"
   }, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: I guess OP is using jQuery UI which already supports color animation, so no need to include jquery-color plugin